# Union of dense is dense?

Tags: general-topology

**Question**:In topological space, union of any family of dense subset is dense?

I don't know whether the above statement is true or not! I know the definition of dense sets in topological space. According to "me  it **may not be true**, as closure of infinite Union may not be equals to Union of closures. please help me to prove the above **or** give counter example of above..

Comment: I don't known, why negative votes? I am quite good in Real analysis. But question is for "general topological space" and I am beginner in topology. So one can have questions like this. Really beginner may face downvoting :-(

Comment: I've just upvoted you :) some advice for the future: write it in a "mathematical" language and it will be much more approved :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. For all subsets $A,B$ of $X$: $A \subseteq B$ implies $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{B}$.
2. $A$ is dense means $\overline{A} = X$.
3. So $A$ dense and $A \subseteq B$ then $B$ is dense.
4. $A_j \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ for any $ j \in I$.

So if in a union of sets at least one of them is dense, so is the union.

Comment: Wait, does the bar over a set mean the closure or the complement of the set? If it's the complement, I don't believe that first statement is true. for $A = \{1,2\}, B = \{1,2,3\}, X = \{1,2,3,4\}$ then $\overline{A} = \{3,4\}, \overline{B} = \{4\}$ and so $\overline{A} \not\subset \overline{B}$

Comment: @Shufflepants closure not complement.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is true.  Given one dense set you can find a sequence converging to any point of the space.  Adding in more points to your set cannot remove any sequences, so you can still find a sequence converging to any point in the space.  As an example, think of the rationals in $\Bbb R$.  They are dense.  Another dense set is the rationals times $\sqrt 2$.  If I take the union of those, I can find a sequence converging to any real.  I can just ignore the rationals times $\sqrt 2$ and use the sequence of rationals that I already had.

Comment: You cannot always find such a sequence (in general spaces), but just use that $A \subseteq B$ implies $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{B}$. If $A$ is dense, its closure is $X$ and thus so is the closure of any larger set.

Answer (score 3):

Only if the family is non-empty, but if so, then it follows because any superset of a dense subset is dense.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a family of dense subsets in a topological space $X$, then for a fixed $n$, we have

$$A_n\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\Rightarrow X=\overline{A_n}\subset\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty {A_n}}$$

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to look at alternative definitions of density.
There are several, and some make this property more transparent than others.
For example a set $A\subset X$ is dense iff for any non-empty open set $U\subset X$ we have $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$.
That is, a set is dense when it meets every open set.
Now if you take a bigger set $A'\supset A$ (whether it is a union or something else), then every open set has an element of $A$ and therefore an element of $A'$.